# Avoid oscillations of the curve fitting

Tags: python, algorithm, math, optimization, scipy

I have got experimental data (orange points). This data do not have any oscillations by nature. 
I do [curve fitting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) (polynomial) and obtain green points. As you may see there are some oscillations closer to the beginning of x-axis.

I came up with the idea of dividing initial data by several parts (based on derivations for example) and do curve fitting of each part with additional conditions on boundaries (equivalent of the first and the second derivations).

Before I start to implement it I would like to find out if there is any implementation of similar algorithm? Or maybe can you advice me another method of avoiding oscillations?

[image]

Comment: How exactly are you doing the fit? You might want to try spline fitting.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, Do you mean https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline ?

Comment: lower the degree of polynomial ... or use piecewise low degree polynomials like SPLINE/BEZIER or Interpolation cubics ... The oscilations are due to too big degree of fitted polynomial where even a slight (like FPU rounding) error of coefficients results in oscillations ....

Comment: @NicoSchertler, I need to use aproximation only. Interpolation is incorrect in my case.

Comment: @Spektre, of course I tried lower the degree of polynomial. "piecewise low degree polynomials" is want I want. I want to find the implementation or function in scipy or similar.

Comment: you should provide your code.  The curve_fit function is very flexible and there are many things you might be doing wrong.

Comment: What is the degree of the model that was fit to produce that graph?

Comment: What do you want to use the model for?

Comment: @MattTimmermans

I need just sew two polynoms! https://ibb.co/d2pugF here is a problem, I need to add additional conditions to LLS calculation. The equality of the first and the second derivatives. It will be enough for me.